# Get class property name ,their type and if collection then collection's generic type

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
public class Table{
private Long id = 1;
private String name;
List<Terms> terms;
Map<String,Address>
//getters and setters
}
```

what i need to do is that i need to link my class tables with database table and each element in the above class is a concept in database table and i have whole structure of java classes as per my xml and related database tables in DB what should be the best way.
as per my understanding what can i think as of now is that

1. use reflection to get the fields name and apply my business logic
2. Use XPath of my xml and directly link each concept using XPath
3. Each time get the value from DB and XML and link it using some mediator logic.

Please suggest and provide some code dummy code if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    You can try with below example:

    Iterator<Table> iterator=tableList.iterator();
    boolean foundConcept=false;
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        foundConcept=false;
    Table table=iterator.next();
    String conceptName=table.getConceptDetails().getName();
    Field fieldArr[]=Table.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    List<Field> fields=Arrays.asList(fieldArr);
     Iterator<Field> iterator1 =fields.iterator();
    int i=0;
    while(iterator1.hasNext())
    {
    Field field=iterator1.next();
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(field.getName()+"  @   "+field.getType());
    if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(conceptName) &&     String.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
    {
    foundConceptMap.put(conceptName, (field.get(Table)).toString());
    foundConcept=true;
    break;
    }
    else
       {
       Type type = field.getGenericType();
    if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)type;
    System.out.print("Raw type: " + pType.getRawType() + " - ");
    System.out.println("Type args: " + pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    if("java.util.List".equalsIgnoreCase(pType.getRawType().getTypeName()))
    {
        String classWithPackage=pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName();
        String className="";
        if(classWithPackage.contains("."))
        {
            className=classWithPackage.substring(classWithPackage.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        }
        else
        {
        className=classWithPackage;
        }
        System.out.println(className);

        if("Terms".equalsIgnoreCase(className))
        {
            List<Terms> list=Table.getTerms();
            setTerms(list, foundConceptMap, conceptName);
        }
    }
    }
    }
```